# Why is $(\textrm{Ker } \beta)^0 = (\textrm{Ker } \alpha)^0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, root-systems

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group, $\beta$ a root of a maximal torus $T$ of $G$, $S = (\textrm{Ker } \beta)^0$, and assume that $Z_G(S)$ is not solvable.  Then $T$ is a maximal torus of $Z_G(S)$, and the Weyl group $W(Z_G(S),T)$ has order $2$.  Hence $Z_G(S)$ has semisimple rank $1$ (Theorem 25.3, Humphreys).  Hence $H = Z_G(S)/R_u$ is reductive of semisimple rank one, where $R$ is the radical of $Z_G(S)$.

The restriction of the map $\pi: Z_G(S) \rightarrow H$ to $T$ is an isomorphism of $T$ onto a maximal torus $\pi(T)$ of $H$, because $T \cap R_u = 1$.  So we can think of $\beta$ as a character $\beta'$ of $\pi(T)$.

If we know something about reductive groups of semisimple rank one like $H$, we know that there are only two roots $\alpha', -\alpha'$ of $H$ whose weight spaces are each one dimensional.  We can interpret these characters as characters $\alpha, -\alpha$ of $T$.

The claim in the book I'm reading (Springer, *Linear Algebraic Groups*) is that $$(\textrm{Ker } \alpha)^0 = (\textrm{Ker } \beta)^0$$  I don't see why, is this obvious?

[image]

My attempt at proving this was to note that the Lie algebra of $Z_G(S)$ contains the weight space $\mathfrak g_{\beta}$.  So there exists a $0 \neq X \in \mathscr L(Z_G(S))$ such that $$\textrm{Ad }t(X) = \beta(t)X, t \in T$$

Going modulo $\mathscr L(R_u)$, and using the facts that $\mathfrak t \cap \mathscr L(R_u) = 0$ (since $T \cap R_u = 1$), and that $$\mathscr L (Z_G(S)/R_u) \cong \mathscr L(Z_G(S))/\mathscr L(R_u)$$

we get that the image of $X$ in $\mathscr L(H)$ is in the root space of $\beta'$.  (However, the image of $X$ might be $0$, in fact we might have $\mathscr L(\mathfrak g_{\beta}) \subseteq \mathscr L(R_u)$ for all we know)  That would imply that $\beta'$ is a root of $\pi(T)$ in $H$, which implies $\beta = \pm \alpha$.  This is stronger than what Springer claims.  But of course this might not happen, as I just mentioned in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess after changing your $\beta$ to a constant multiple of it  (which still lies in $P'$ automatically), you will be able to choose such an X in the lie algebra which is nonzero when passing to the quotient.

This is because, if this does not happen, centralizer of $ker(\alpha)$ would consist of your maximal torus plus something in the unipotent radical. And this would make it solvable which contradicts the fact that it is in $P'$

Answer (score 0):

(It being 5 years later, you've certainly worked this out by now; but no answer was accepted, so I thought I'd write it out for anyone else who encountered the issue.)

It's often important to understand while reading Springer that all constructions are performed in the category of *smooth* groups.  Thus Springer means by $\ker(\beta)^\circ$ what is really the smooth reduced scheme $\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}$ underlying the identity component of the scheme-theoretic kernel of $\beta$ (so that Springer's $\ker(\beta)^\circ$ is a torus, rather than an infinitesimal extension of a torus).  In terms of character lattices, the difference is that the character group of the scheme-theoretic $\ker(\beta)^\circ$ might have $p$-torsion, whereas the character group of Springer's $\ker(\beta)^\circ$ quotients out this $p$-torsion (hence is torsion-free, the other torsion having been removed by passage to the identity component).

$\DeclareMathOperator\X{X}$The character lattice of $T/\ker(\beta)$ is $\mathbb Z\beta \subseteq \operatorname X^*(T)$, more or less by definition of the kernel as the smallest normal subgroup such that $\beta$ factors through the quotient.  The character lattice of $T/\ker(\beta)^\circ$ in the scheme-theoretic sense kills off any possible étale quotient of $\ker(\beta)$ (on the group side) by killing off all prime-to-$p$ torsion in $\X^*(\ker(\beta)) \cong \X^*(T)/\X^*(T/\ker(\beta))$.  That is, the character lattice of $T/\ker(\beta)^\circ$ in the scheme-theoretic sense consists of all characters of $T$ some prime-to-$p$ multiple of which lie in $\X^*(T/\ker(\beta)) = \mathbb Z\beta$.  In other words, it is $\mathbb Z_{(p)}\beta \cap \X^*(T)$.  Finally, using Springer's sense, the character lattice of $T/\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}$ consists of all characters of $T$ some multiple of which lie in $\mathbb Z\beta$, where now we allow multiples divisible by $p$.  In other words, it is $\mathbb Q\beta \cap \X^*(T)$.  This shows that two characters of $T$ have the same *smooth* connected kernel if and only if one is a non-$0$ rational multiples of the other.

I had to go hunting for the definition of $P'$, which is in §7.1.4.  The characters $\pm\alpha'$—from which I'll drop the primes because, as Springer points out, they are really characters of $T$—are the non-$0$ weights of (the image of) $T$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G_\beta)$.  Since $\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}$ acts trivially on $\operatorname{Lie}(G_\beta) = \operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname C_G(\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red})) = \operatorname C_{\operatorname{Lie}(G)}(\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red})$, we have that $\alpha$ lies in $\X^*(T/\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}) = \mathbb Q\beta \cap \X^*(T)$.  Since $\alpha$ is non-trivial by Lemma 7.2.3, we are done.

(Incidentally, *after* having worked with the smaller connected kernel, we can show that we would have got the same answer had we worked with the larger one; for, since $\ker(\beta)^\circ$ in the scheme-theoretic sense contains Springer's $\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}$, the containment of centralisers is reversed, giving that $\operatorname C_G(\ker(\beta)^\circ)$ is contained in $\operatorname C_G(\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red})$.  Thus we may replace $G$ by $C_G(\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red})$, and so suppose that $\ker(\beta)^\circ_\text{red}$ is central in the first place.  I claim that $\ker(\beta)^\circ$, and even $\ker(\beta)$ is central in $G$.  But then $G$ is of semisimple rank $1$, and the classification in §7.3.2 shows that there are only two non-$0$ weights of $T$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, which must therefore be $\pm\beta$, so that, as you suspected, $\alpha = \pm\beta$, and the centre of $G$ is precisely the kernel of $\beta$.)